# Error "Use of \next@ doesn't match its definition" with xy?

Tags: errors, xy-pic

I'm trying to compile the following simple code:

```
\xymatrix{ 
A \ar[r] ^a="a"
& B \ar[r] ^b="b" & C
\ar @/^/ "a";"b" }
```

but I always get the following error:  **Use of \next@ doesn't match its definition.**

The problem seems to be when I name the arrows "a" and "b". How can I solve this? Is there a connection with my preamble? I am loading babel in my preamble.

Thanks

Comment: If I add a standard preamble, I get no error. Please, make an example that produces the issue.

Comment: I'm almost sure that the problem is using quotes in `xy` with `babel`. Are you using `babel` with some latin based language?

Comment: Yes, I'm using babel with with the parameter brazilian.

Comment: Load babel with the option for disabling shorthands, such as in `\usepackage[shorthands=off,german]{babel}`. Babel redefines the quotes in a manner incompatible with xypic. This can be turned off with shorthands=off.

Comment: Not sure why this question has been closed. It is pretty much a precise question, especially with the comment.